# Android Firebase Storage : User does not have permission to access this object

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

This storage allows me upload an image

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

But this doesn't work

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

My Java Code

```
private void uploadFile() {
    //if there is a file to upload
    if (filePath != null) {
        //displaying a progress dialog while upload is going on
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading");
        progressDialog.show();

        StorageReference riversRef = storageReference.child("images/pic.jpg");
        riversRef.putFile(filePath)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        //if the upload is successfull
                        //hiding the progress dialog
                        progressDialog.dismiss();

                        //and displaying a success toast
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File Uploaded ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                        //if the upload is not successfull
                        //hiding the progress dialog
                        progressDialog.dismiss();

                        //and displaying error message
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                })
                .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        //calculating progress percentage
                        double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();

                        //displaying percentage in progress dialog
                        progressDialog.setMessage("Uploaded " + ((int) progress) + "%...");
                    }
                });
    }
    //if there is not any file
    else {
        //you can display an error toast
    }
}
```

Google recommends to have request.auth != null
Then why doesn't it work?

What does that code exactly mean and why am I unable to work with it.

I exactly want to ask what is that line for and why removing it works?
Doesn't removing it mean that anybody can access my storage?

Comment: Do you authenticate your user before you try to access storage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These [rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/) are related to Authentication([Firebase Auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth))

> allow read, write; **: No security, no need for the firebase authentication** (Allow access by all users)
>
> allow read, write: if request.auth != null; **: Only authenticated users can read or write to the bucket**

if you want to work with auth!= null, then you need to sign in the user with [Firebase Auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth)

Comment: Hey @majuran , can you share me any document to do that?